# Uncaught Exeption iin /iris/ws (also [Errno 101] Network unreachable)

Tags: python, linux, centos, python-iris

I started to install MOPIDY on a "Centos 7"-Virtual Machine.
Everything works fine, I also installed a Web client named "Iris".

I can connect to Spotify, but the "Pusher" (i think "iris"!?) connects and disconnects again and again and again. I don't know why and I also get some errors in my terminal. I don't know where to look to fix the Problems, maybe you have any tips Guys?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this are not the Iris you are looking for ?
http://scitools.org.uk/iris/

Comment: No, the Iris i mean is a http-client for MOPIDY. Is my Tag wrong?